# Strange NumberFormatException in Hibernate When Using SessionFactory

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, hibernate

[It may be useful to see my related, yet distinct, question from earlier today here [Hibernate Schema Export in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465173/hibernate-schema-export-in-eclipse) .]

I have the following Java class

```
package com.examscam.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
        config.configure();
//      new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User u = new User();        
        u.setPassword("abc123");

        session.saveOrUpdate(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

I have a (MySQL) database and have created the User table with the code

```
create table User (id integer not null auto_increment, password varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

However, when I try running this code, I am given the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.util.PropertiesHelper.getInteger(PropertiesHelper.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:40)
```

Line 40 of the User class is

```
    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I am not entering an empty String anywhere on that line and I have copied the code exactly from the book. I have no doubt that the book is correct; my questions is more along the lines of 'Can anyone think of any reason (errors in xml files, classpath ordering issues, files not being in the correct directories etc) why this behaviour would occur?'.

An answer to this question might also help solve the issue in the link at the very top of this page with exporting the schema.

Thanks, Conor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I've solved this problem which ended up being two problems.  First, there was another older copy of hibernate in the classpath.  This older version was requiring config elements that no longer were required, leading to the `NumberFormatException` as it was trying to parse an empty string into an int for the missing transaction isolation config element.

After fixing that, we started to see a `NullPointerException` on this line of code:

```
Environment.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stripped);
```

Looking at that line of code, the only thing that could have been throwing the `NPE` was the `getClassLoader` call, but how could that ever be null?  As it turns out `getClassLoader` can return null if the class loader being returned is the boot class loader.  I asked Conor to check if he had put hibernate into the boot class path and it turns out that he did.  Removing it from the boot class fixed the issue.

So two lessons here:

1. Manage your class path carefully.  Know what's on it and keep it as trim as possible.  The less 3rd party libs the better.
2. Don't ever put stuff on the boot class path.  If you decide to ignore this rule, understand what the potential implications are so you're not stuck chasing issues like this.

Comment: I provided my full entry for hibernate.cfg.xml on the page that I linked to at the tope of the post, but it just contains hibernate.connection.url, hibernate.connection.username, hibernate.connection.password, hibernate.connection.driver_class, hibernate.dialect, hibernate.transaction.factory_class, hibernate.current_session_context_class and hibernate.show_sql. Again, I have copied this code exactly as it is from the book. Having said that, it is slightly out of date. Can you think of anything else I need? I downloaded all hibernate jars this morning, so it should be the most recent version.

Comment: The exact version of hibernate is important here as it tells me what source code to look at.  Can you give me the exact version?

Comment: The hibernate core that I'm using is hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar. Is that what you need [I'm something of a novice]?

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you! It's good to know the origin of the issue. I have looked through my classpath and there are other hibernate jars that look like they could be the offenders (in particular, hibernate3.jar seems suspicious - the book I'm using specifically mentioned it but this was back when Annotations were not included with hibernate core, so I had to improvise a bit in some place, which clearly hasn't worked flawlessly); I have elevated hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar to the top of my classpath. This now produces a different exception, which I'll detail below.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2023)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1935)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)

Comment: at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:177)
 at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:37)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: null Nested exception: null
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2015)
 ... 8 more

Comment: So it's not happy with my hibernate config for some reason. Can you suggest what the problem might be? Thank you so much for all of this! You're amazing!

Comment: I'm guessing it's not able to find your config file thus the null failure from DOM4J.  Are you sure you are putting your config file in the correct location so that the it can be found?

Comment: The book I'm working from says that hibernate.cfg.xml needs to be on the classpath, as well as being available to the classloader so that runs the Hibernate Configuration code. It then suggests that a good place to put it would be in the root of the src directory where the Java code is written to, as well as being copied into the build directory where compiled byte-code is placed. So I found where my User.java file is, found the src super-directory and put hibernate.cfg.xml in there, as well as in the build directory of src's parent directory.

Comment: The hibernate.cfg.xml file in the src directory is also there with log4j.properties, log4j.xml, hibernate.properties (the last two of which are blank) and the META-INF directory (which contains orm.xml and persistence.xml). Anything sounding wrong yet? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29687/discussion-between-cmbaxter-and-conorw)

Comment: Should probably also add that both src and build have been added to my classpath, with src above build.

Answer (score 0):

The database id column datatype is integer, but entity class's id datatype is long, not sure whether this is the problem. 
But it is worth giving a try to changed the datatype of entity's id to int.

Comment: I see what you mean and I changed the Long to Integer where appropriate but I still get a NumberFormatException, so I guess that's not it. Thanks anyway.